# udpipe (keywords_rake) how to link keywords to the document they where extracted from

Tags: r, nlp, udpipe

I am using the function keywords_rake from the  udpipe package (for R) to extract keywords from a bunch of documents.

```
udmodel_en <- udpipe_load_model(file = dl$file_model)
x <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel_en, x = data$text)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

keywords <- keywords_rake(x = x, term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                          relevant = x$xpos %in% c("NN", "JJ"), ngram_max = 2)
```

where data looks like this

```
  Text
  "cats are nice but dogs are better..."
  "I really like dogs..."
  "red flowers are pretty, especially roses..."
  "once I saw a blue whale ..."
  ....
```

(each row is a separate document)

However the output does not include the origin of the keywords, and provides a list of keywords for all the documents

how can I link these keywords to the corresponding documents they were taken from?
(I.e. have a list of keywords for each of the documents)

something like this:

```
      keywords
doc1   dog, cat, blue whale
doc2   dog 
doc3   red flower, tower, Donald Trump
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `txt_recode_ngram` together with the outcome of `keywords_rake` to do this. The advantage is that everything is back in the original data.frame and you can then select what you need. See example below using the dataset supplied with udpipe.

Disclaimer: Code copied from jwijffels' answer in [issue 41](https://github.com/bnosac/udpipe/issues/41) on the github page of udpipe.

```
data(brussels_reviews_anno)
x <- subset(brussels_reviews_anno, language == "nl")
keywords <- keywords_rake(x = x, term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                          relevant = x$xpos %in% c("NN", "JJ"), sep = "-")
head(keywords)

            keyword ngram freq     rake
1  openbaar-vervoer     2   19 2.391304
2         heel-fijn     2    2 2.236190
3  heel-vriendelijk     2    3 2.131092
4 herhaling-vatbaar     2    6 2.000000
5  heel-appartement     2    2 1.935450
6 steenworp-afstand     2    4 1.888889

x$term <- txt_recode_ngram(x$lemma, compound = keywords$keyword, ngram = keywords$ngram, sep = "-")
x$term <- ifelse(!x$term %in% keywords$keyword, NA, x$term)
head(x[!is.na(x$term), ])

        doc_id language sentence_id token_id       token      lemma xpos                term
67039 19991431       nl        4379       11         erg        erg   JJ        erg-centraal
67048 19991431       nl        4379       20        leuk       leuk   JJ          leuk-adres
67070 21054450       nl        4380        6       goede       goed   JJ        goed-locatie
67077 21054450       nl        4380       13    Europese   europees   JJ       europees-wijk
67272 23542577       nl        4393       84 uitstekende uitstekend   JJ uitstekend-gastheer
67299 40676307       nl        4396       25   gezellige   gezellig   JJ      gezellig-buurt
```

Comment: Is there a way to link phrases extracted using the keywords_phrases to the sentence/document the phrase came from?